# Stuck On A Projectile Motion Question, Is My Answer Correct Or The Textbook Answer?

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, physics, projectile-motion

> A stone is thrown to hit a small target, which is at a distance of $14$ m horizontally and $5.5$ m vertically upwards from the point of projection. The stone is thrown from a height of $2$ m above the horizontal ground with a speed of $42$ m/s. Find, in degrees correct to one decimal place, the angle from the horizontal at which the stone should be thrown to hit the target. (Assume that there is no air resistance.)

**Textbook Answer:** $16.3^\circ$ or $87.8^\circ$
**My Answer:** $23.7^\circ$ or $87.7^\circ$

[image: answer]

Does my textbook have the correct answer or is my answer correct?

Comment: In case you are wondering, I tried to edit the question to display the image directly in the question.  Something misfired, so I deleted my editing.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Don't use picture in the question session. Use MathJax formatting to mathematical expressions. See   https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @user2661923 That imgur address has two images so you need to separately include them when inlining.

Comment: @user10354138 Thanks, the situation had me scratching my head.  I wasn't seeing the *.jpg links.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out the issue. You took the question to mean the target is $14$ metres horizontally and $5.5$ metres vertically from the exact point of release.

The textbook answer is based on the target being $14$ metres horizontally and $5.5$ metres vertically from the point on the ground directly (vertically) below the point of release. In other words, $14$ metres horizontally and only $3.5$ metres vertically from the exact point of release.

I got both sets of answers using the two different interpretations.

For what it's worth, I agree with your interpretation and your answers.

You can generate both sets of answers by solving this quadratic:

$0.545\tau^2 - 14\tau + (H+0.545) = 0$

where $\tau = \tan \theta, \ \theta$ being the required angle of projection from the horizontal, and $H$ being either $5.5$ or $3.5$ based on your interpretation. I took $g = 9.81$ meters per second squared.